# Differential equations and categorical logic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, logic, category-theory, initial-value-problems

In categorical logic, we usually think of each theory as being category $\mathbf{T}$. A model of $\mathbf{T}$ is then a functor $\mathbf{T} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ satisfying some appropriate conditions. And, we can change $\mathbf{Set}$ to other sufficiently-nice categories to get other notions of model. I was wondering whether or not something similar can be done for differential equations/IVP's/integral equations (etc.); can we think of these as some kind of object such that morphisms out of this object "are" solutions to the problem?

Comment: It might not be exactly what you are searching for, but maybe you want to have a look at D-modules? For a differential equation you get a module over the modiule of differential operatiors the hom out of which is the solution functor for this equation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-module, and the introduction of http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/Hotta.pdf is also a very interesting read.

Comment: @Hanno, sounds good!

Comment: [Synthetic differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_differential_geometry) heavily relies categorical logic, albeit not so much on things like Lawvere theories, more toposes and internal languages. The main idea is to make many differential geometry concepts *representable*.  For example, the tangent bundle $TM$ becomes $M^D$. A first order differential equation is then a map $M\to M^D$. With [fractional exponents](http://home.math.au.dk/kock/ODE55.pdf), you can represent a second order differential equation as a map $M\to(M^{D\times D})^{1/D}$.